# Performing conditions on PHP before inserting the data on MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working with a small project. I used HTML for the form where the user can input data and PHP to execute some queries into my database. I'm having a problem on my codes with my PHP script and SQL queries. To illustrate my simple process of submitting the form when the user click the '**Save**' button, here's what I want to happen:

But before that, I have two table named `nca` and `nca_totals` where to save the data.

Table: `nca`

```
+--------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
| nca_id | nca_no  | issue_date | nca_amount | account_type |
+--------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

Table : `nca_totals`

```
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| total_id | nca_total | nca_date   | account_type |
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

Step by step action after hitting '**Save**' button by the user:

1. Insert values to `nca` table. For example here are the values that the user input the form (comma separated means another input from the user):

   ```
   nca_id = 1,2,3
   nca_no = 14-0001,14-0002,14-0001
   issue_date = 2015-01-09,2015-01-09,2015-01-10
   nca_amount = 500,1000,2000
   account_type = DBP-TRUST,DBP-TRUST,ROP
   ```

   My query:

   ```
   // INSERT to nca table
   $sql3 = "INSERT into nca VALUES ('$nca_id','$nca_no','$nca_date','$nca_amount','$nca_account')";    
   $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
   ```

   Here's what it look like when you select the table:

   ```
   +--------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
   | nca_id | nca_no  | issue_date | nca_amount | account_type |
   +--------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
   |      1 | 14-0001 | 2015-01-09 |        500 | DBP-TRUST    |
   |      2 | 14-0002 | 2015-01-09 |       1000 | DBP-TRUST    |
   |      3 | 14-0001 | 2015-01-10 |       2000 | ROP          |
   +--------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
   ```
2. Sum up the `nca_amount` from table `nca` of the same date and year base on the `account_type`.

   Here's my query below:

   ```
   // SUM up amount 
   $sql1 = "SELECT SUM(nca_amount) AS nca_total FROM nca WHERE account_type = '$nca_account' AND 
           (year(issue_date) = year('$nca_date') AND
           month(issue_date) = month('$nca_date'))";
   $result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
   while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
       $db_ncaTotal = $row1['nca_total'];                                                          
   }

   // Insert to nca_totals table
   $sql4 = "INSERT into nca_totals VALUES ('','$db_ncaTotal','$nca_date','$nca_account')"; 
   $result4 = mysql_query($sql4);
   ```

   Here's what it looks like in the table `nca_totals`:

   ```
   +----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
   | total_id | nca_total | nca_date   | account_type |
   +----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
   |        1 | 500       | 2015-01-09 | DBP-TRUST    |
   |        2 | 1500      | 2015-01-09 | DBP-TRUST    |
   |        3 | 2000      | 2015-01-10 | ROP          |
   +----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
   ```

As what it looks like on the result above on my `nca_totals`, it saves the `SUM` of `nca_amount` having the `account_type` of DBP-TRUST and date of 2015-01-09. The result is 1500.

Illustration below to explain it clearly:

```
1 | 14-0001 | 2015-01-09 |        500 | DBP-TRUST    |
2 | 14-0002 | 2015-01-09 |       1000 | DBP-TRUST    |
```

My query of `sql1` variable above would result to 500 + 1000 = **1500** and that what I want to happen. But as you can see on `nca_totals` table, it still has the result from my previous calculation of the sum of `nca_amount`.

This is what I want only to be in my `nca_totals` table without the previous calculated sum of `nca_amount` from `nca` table.

```
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| total_id | nca_total | nca_date   | account_type |
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
|        1 | 1500      | 2015-01-09 | DBP-TRUST    | ---- Just this result to save
|        2 | 2000      | 2015-01-10 | ROP          |
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

How can I do that? Can I do that with conditioning in my PHP or in the query? Really need help for this. My codes are really a mess here. It's not doing what I expected. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

with this codes, you must check nca_totals table before insert! if with that acc_type and date data exist update and if not exist insert row!

```
$sql_chk = "SELECT nca_total FROM nca_totals WHERE account_type = '$nca_account' AND substring(nca_date,1,7) = substring('$nca_date',1,7)";
$result_chk = mysql_query($sql_chk);

if (mysql_num_rows($result_chk)==0) { 
  $sql4 = "INSERT into nca_totals VALUES ('','$db_ncaTotal','$nca_date','$nca_account')"; 
  $result4 = mysql_query($sql4);
}else{
  $sql4 = "update nca_totals set VALUES nca_total='$db_ncaTotal' WHERE account_type = '$nca_account' AND substring(nca_date,1,7) = substring('$nca_date',1,7)"; 
  $result4 = mysql_query($sql4);
}
```

just replace this code with this insert code !

```
// Insert to nca_totals table
$sql4 = "INSERT into nca_totals VALUES ('','$db_ncaTotal','$nca_date','$nca_account')"; 
$result4 = mysql_query($sql4);
```

if you can use mysqli against mysql!